# No expansion error found for :default in rails using jquery development jquery.min production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following line in my development.rb file:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions = { :default => [:jquery] }
```

and the following in my production.rb file:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions = { :default => ["jquery.min"] }
```

I have installed a jquery to be used in my rails app with the jquery gem.  No prototype installed.

I have uncommented the following line in my application.rb file:

```
  # JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
     config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)
```

I want to user regular jquery for development and then jquery mini  for production.  This configuration causes the following error:

No expansion found for :defaults

How can I fix this error while still having different jquery environments for production and development?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling it the wrong name. You're saying it's `:default` when it should be `:defaults`. The code in your `config/environment.rb` and `config/environments/*` files will be overriding whatever it is that is in `application.rb`.

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan. That is it. You saved me a lot of grief.